# ViewBag property value in DropDownListFor instead of Model property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We found strange behaviour in DropDownListFor (ASP.NET MVC3 release). It selects ViewBag property value instead of Model property value in dropdown.

Model:

```
public class Country {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class User {
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Index action:

```
ViewBag.CountryList = new List<Country> {  /* Dropdown collection */
   new Country() { Name = "Danmark" }, 
   new Country() { Name = "Russia" } }; 

var user = new User();
user.Country = new Country(){Name = "Russia"}; /* User value */
ViewBag.Country = new Country() { Name = "Danmark" };  /* It affects user */
return View(user);
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(user => user.Country.Name)      
@Html.DropDownListFor(user => user.Country.Name,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "Name", "Name", Model.Country), "...")
```

It will show text box with "Russia" value and dropdown with "Danmark" value selected instead of "Russia".

I didn't find any documentation about this behaviour. Is this behaviour normal? And why is it normal? Because it is very hard to control ViewBag and Model properties names.

[This sample MVC3 project sources](http://musuk.info/download/files/MvcApplication1.zip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not so sure why this decision was made, but it was happened because MVC framework tried to use the ViewData-supplied value before using the parameter-supplied value. That's why `ViewBag.Country` override parameter-supplied value `Model.Country`.

That was how it was [written](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.aspx) in MVC framework in the **private** method `SelectInternal`.

```
object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string[])) : htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));

// If we haven't already used ViewData to get the entire list of items then we need to
// use the ViewData-supplied value before using the parameter-supplied value.
if (!usedViewData) {
    if (defaultValue == null) {
        defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(fullName);
    }
}

if (defaultValue != null) {
    IEnumerable defaultValues = (allowMultiple) ? defaultValue as IEnumerable : new[] { defaultValue };
    IEnumerable<string> values = from object value in defaultValues select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    HashSet<string> selectedValues = new HashSet<string>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    List<SelectListItem> newSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList) {
        item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) : selectedValues.Contains(item.Text);
        newSelectList.Add(item);
    }
    selectList = newSelectList;
}
```

This code `defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(fullName);` tried to get the value from `ViewData` and if it can get the value, it will override the supplied parameter `selectList` with new list.

Hope it can help. Thanks.

*side-node*: ViewBag is just a dynamic wrapper class of ViewData.

Answer (score 4):

The following line from your action method is what is confusing the code:

```
ViewBag.Country = new Country() { Name = "Danmark" };  /* It affects user */
```

That's because the html helpers look into a few different places to pick up values for the generated controls. In this case `ViewData["Country"]` is clashing with `ModelState["Country"]` Rename that property to something else and everything should work.

Comment: Do you suggest always use prefix for ViewBag property name to avoid name clashing? Ex. ViewBag.ViewBag_Country

Comment: holy crap, you're right. Thank you for this... saved my day... :)